# Django static css file

Tags: django

> ***Project***

```
myblog-
   |
   |-static
      |  
      |-Css
         | 
         |-bootstrap.css
```

> ** Setting.py**

```
  STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')      
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)


**urls**

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from myblog.views import hello, current_datetime, hours_ahead

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    url(r'^hello/$',hello),
    url(r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    url(r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/',include('blog.urls')),
]  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

> **Templates/base.html**

```
  {% load staticfiles %}
    <link href="{% static 'base/css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

After running  manage.py runserver 192.168.8.213:8080. It shows Page not found (404) Request Method:    GET Request
     URL:   http://192.168.8.213:8080/static/base/css/bootstrap.cs`enter code here`s Raised by: blog.views.index

```
 'base/css/bootstrap.css' could not be found

 You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
 settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
 standard 404 page.`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 4):

- We have to load static file into individual app, when we are on debug mode.
- And In project name aPP folder, we will load the static folder

  ### In setting.py
- We have to define the path

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myblog/static'),
 )

### In production

- If we write "python manage.py colltecstatic" ,it will copy the static file in root static folder.